# $ variable is ignore in command k8s yaml

Tags: kubernetes, sh

I defined k8s pod yaml file and I want to run bash script in initcontainer. When I run it and check k8s dashboard in container yaml, $ip_list variable is removed.

```
  initContainers:
    - name: init-redis
      image: busybox:1.36.1-glibc
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          until [ $(nslookup headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local | grep
          'Address: ' | awk '{print $2}' | wc -w) = 3 ]; do echo
          Waiting-all-instances...; sleep 1; done; for ip_list in $(nslookup
          headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }'); do until nc -vz $ip_list
          80; do echo waiting-SENTINEL...; sleep 1; done; done;
```

in k8s dashboard

```
  initContainers:
    - name: init-redis
      image: busybox:1.36.1-glibc
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          until [ $(nslookup headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local | grep
          'Address: ' | awk '{print $2}' | wc -w) = 3 ]; do echo
          Waiting-all-instances...; sleep 1; done; for ip_list in $(nslookup
          headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local | awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }'); do until nc -vz
          80; do echo waiting-SENTINEL...; sleep 1; done; done;
```

Comment: How are you applying this yaml?

Comment: @jordanm   I use basic pod creation yaml.

Comment: Can you add to the question the exact command you run?

Comment: The YAML formatting is really messy, are you sure there are no syntax errors in that? Surely you should be able to apply natural line breaks in the code even if it's embedded in a YAML file?

Comment: I don't think Busybox has Bash ...? And your script is explicitly using `sh`. See also [Difference between Bash and `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your YAML processor is performing some sort of interpolation of the values. Maybe try to escape the problematic dollar sign?

Anyway, adding quotes around the IP address should at least reveal when it's going wrong. The following refactoring also attempts to remove several shell scripting code smells.

```yaml
  initContainers:
    - name: init-redis
      image: busybox:1.36.1-glibc
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          until nslookup headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local |
               awk '/Address:/ { ++n }
                 END { if(n!=3) print "Waiting-all-instances";
                   exit (n!=3) }';
          do
            sleep 1;
          done;
          nslookup headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local |
          awk '/^Address: / { print $2 }' |
          while read -r ip; do
            until nc -vz "$ip" 80; do
              echo waiting-SENTINEL...;
              sleep 1;
          done
```

(I'm guessing [most of] the semicolons might be unnecessary, but I left them in just in case your YAML processor wraps everything back on effectively a single line.)

Running the same `nslookup` multiple times is a bit of an antipattern, too; perhaps even try

```yaml
  initContainers:
    - name: init-redis
      image: busybox:1.36.1-glibc
      command:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >-
          while true; do
              ips=$(nslookup headless-svc.default.svc.cluster.local |
                   awk '/^Address:/ { print $2 }
                     END { if(n!=3) print "Waiting-all-instances";
                       exit (n!=3) }') && break;
              sleep 1;
          done;
          for ip in $ips; do
              until nc -vz "$ip" 80; do
                  echo waiting-SENTINEL...;
                  sleep 1;
              done;
          done
```